# How to get the week of the month along with the date range in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have the query which returns me the week of the month but I wanted the date range along with that. How do I alter my query to get the date range for the week.This is my query:

```
select 
 date,
 FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS week,
 Concat('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) + 1) AS weekname 
from table_test 
 where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y')='".$monYear."'" 
group by week
```

Here the variable $monYear equals "10/2017".

The week starts from sunday to saturday and the first week of the month starts from 01
So, the output should be like this:

> Week 1 : 01/10/2107 - 07/10/2017
>
> Week 2: 08/10/2017 - 14/10/2017
>
> Week 3: 15/10/2017 - 21/10/2017
>
> Week 4: 22/10/2017 - 28/10/2017
>
> Week 5: 29/10/2017 - 31/10/2017

Ok so I tried this, its almost correct but it gives me wrong results for '09/2017'. It gives me 20170896 as startDay for week 1 (96 is wrong) and also it doesnt give me the slashes in between.

```
select date-dayofweek(date)+1 as startDay, 
date+ 7 - dayofweek(date) as endDate,
FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS week,
from table_test where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y')='09/2017' group by week
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to define *week of the month.*  According to your business rules, do weeks run Sunday to Saturday, or Monday to Sunday? Is the week containing the first day of each month considered the first week of the month?

Comment: Still struggling, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sure someone can offer something maybe a little more 'slick', but this works in my tests:

```
SELECT 
date,
week,
weekname,
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as 'Week Start',
IF(DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom, 
      eom,
      DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as 'Week End'
FROM (
   SELECT
    date,
    FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7 +1) AS week,
    CONCAT('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) +1) AS weekname,
    DATE_ADD(date,interval -DAY(date)+1 DAY) AS firstOfMonth,
    LAST_DAY(date) as 'eom'
FROM table_test 
 WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y')='06/2017' 
GROUP BY week
) a
```

(Note:  You have 31 Days in June in your example, when there's only 30, but the above otherwise matched your expected output for me)

```
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------+
|   date    | week | weekname | Week Start |  Week End  |
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------+
| 2017-06-06|  1   |  Week 1  | 2017-06-01 | 2017-06-07 |
| 2017-06-12|  2   |  Week 2  | 2017-06-08 | 2017-06-14 |
| 2017-06-17|  3   |  Week 3  | 2017-06-15 | 2017-06-21 |
| 2017-06-22|  4   |  Week 4  | 2017-06-22 | 2017-06-28 |
| 2017-06-29|  5   |  Week 5  | 2017-06-29 | 2017-06-30 |
+-----------+------+----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Yeah it's almost correct but the week end of 'week 1' is wrong and also there is no 'week 3'

Comment: Have you tested it?  It's probably my sample data and pasting at fault

Comment: I've updated the pasted output - there's nothing wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

The [dayofweek()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) function returns the position of the day within a week, with Sunday as 1.

`yourdate-dayofweek(yourdate)+1` will give you the date of the first day of the week (assuming your first day of the week is Sunday).

`yourdate + 7 - dayofweek(yourdate)` will return the date of the last day of the week (assuming your first day of the week is Sunday).

If you want to have Monday as the first day, then use the [weekday()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) function that returns the index of the day with Monday as 0.

`yourdate-weekday(yourdate)` will give you the date of the first day of the week in this case.

`yourdate + 6 - weekday(yourdate)` will return the date of the last day of the week.

Comment: but the main thing which I want is the date range.i.e. The week 1 starts from 0109/2017 and ends at 08/09/2017 and so on......

Comment: The first and the last day will give you just that.

Comment: I'm trying to add the dayofweek() in my query but I can't seem to get it working. Can you please add this in my query and show me?

Comment: Also if I try to do this for 09/2017 it gives me 20170896 as start date which is wrong

Comment: @SaeeshTendulkar I do not know what you have tried, so I cannot possibly figure out what could have gone wrong.

Comment: select date-dayofweek(date)+1 as startDay, date+ 7 - dayofweek(date)
 date, FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) + 1 AS week, Concat('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(date) - 1) / 7) + 1) AS weekname from table_test  where DATE_FORMAT(date,'%m/%Y')='09/2017' group by week